# Backbone view is not getting displayed

Tags: backbone.js

I am a newbie to Backbone programming. 
Why my collection is not being posted to the server?

```
var VisitModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/book',
    defaults: {
      "startTime" : ""
      "visitType" : "Outsider"
    }
});

var VisitCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: VisitModel,
    urlRoot: '/visit'
});
```

In my view.js:

```
this.collection = new BookCollection();
this.model = new BookModel({"startTime" : new Date().getTime()});
this.collection.add(this.model);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `this.collection.save()` or no data is sent to the server.